# NeoLoad monitoring server under stress

Tags: automated-tests, load-testing, stress-testing, neoload

I am configuring NeoLoad to monitoring my localhost machine as a server. I just want to monitoring some linux process like CPU, MEMORY(USE, FREE).

There are my steps:

#### Start Configuration

I select the `New monitored machine`

[image]

#### Select the Linux Monitor

[image]

#### Configuring monitor

Set the `user and password` and select the `ssh` as protocol connection. Nothing else was configured.

[image]

#### Checking the list of parameters to monitoring.

[image]

#### Select the eth0 interface from the list

[image]

#### Run the monitoring

When I play the test I get this errors:

[image]

I am lost with these errors. I follow the video:  [Monitoring Servers Under Web Stress](http://www.neotys.com/product/demo-neoload.html) to do my custom configuration.

Answer (score 1):

@Robert

NeoLoad cannot be used as a standalone monitoring tool. It will be able to monitor a particular infrastructure only during the execution of a load test. Try to run a single user load test on an application (even a sample application would do) and then try to configure these monitors.

The errors that are present indicate that 
1 & 2 : Since you are not running a load test, there are no load generators and no populations. Hence the line to add at least one Load Generator and create a scenario that references a particular population.